# Convert MS SQL to PostgreSQL query for a KPI

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I just joined Stack overflow and very new to SQL.

I am trying to write a query using PostgreSQL to calculate some KPIs for stores.

The query I am now stuck should give me Monthly revenue per store per customer.

I have googled a lot, wrote something and a friend checked and corrected it, but still doesn't work. I think it is because I may have mixed up MS SQL with PostgreSQL. I am very new to this and I need to make it work for PostgreSQL:

Query that doesn't work in PostgreSQL below:

```
select store_code, customer_id , left(convert(char(8),cast(purchased_at as date),112),6) mnth, sum(cast(rl.value as numeric(18,2))) rev
  FROM  receipts r
  join receipt_lines rl on r.receipt_id=rl.receipt_id
    group by store_code,customer_id,left(convert(char(8),cast(purchased_at as date),112),6) 
  order by 1 asc ,3
```

Once fixed, I will want to connect it to Tableau to visualize some graphs and dashboards out of it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Doesn't work is not very descriptive - are you getting an error or is it not returning the output you expect?

Comment: Hi P. Salmon,

Sorry, I was getting an error message. And when I fixed it, another error was coming. So it had multiple errors and I wasn't getting an output at all. In the end I was chaotically just changing things, which made it only worse.

Answer (score 0):

The version in Postgres might look like this:

```
select store_code, customer_id , to_char(purchased_at, 'YYYYMM') as yyyymm, 
       sum(cast(rl.value as numeric(18, 2))) rev
from receipts r join
     receipt_lines rl
     on r.receipt_id = rl.receipt_id
group by store_code, customer_id, yyyymm
order by store_code asc, yyyymm;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon ! I was banging my head on it for hours.

This was much helpful. I took it, made a few changes and it did work !
There seems to be quite a significant difference between both MS SQL and PostgreSQL as syntax.

Very confusing for me as a totally new to the field.